# WCF - "Incomplete" WSDL with reference to another WSDL

Tags: php, .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I am using SoapClient to send some data from a PHP site to a .Net WCF service.
This is my (shortened for clarity) code:

```
$wsdl = '/var/www/libraries/MyWsdl.xml';
$myClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
```

and later, the actual call:

```
try {           
    $res = $myClient->Foo($someParameter);
}
catch(SoapFault $e){
    //...
}
catch(Exception $e){
    //...
}
```

This works great when everything is online, and the error handling works if the destination server is down on the time `Foo` is called.
Problem is that the `SoapClient` constructor fails, if the destination server is down, even though i've provided it with a static XML file with the WSDL (in oppose to a URL like "`http://www.destination.com/MyService?wsdl`").

I believe this is happening because the WSDL contains a reference to another WSDL:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://MyCompany.Services" location="http://www.destination.com/MyService?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

This other WSDL contains the definitions of the call parameters.

**So, how can I "Inline" the second "sub-WSDL" inside the original one?

Will this allow me to create a `SoapClient` without initiating a connection to the destination server?**

---

This is my service definition:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://MyCompany.Services")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
    string Foo(string myParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the single WSDL-file extension from here: http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

Note that when using .net4.5 there should be no need for it, as the default metadata endpoint now also generates single WSDL-files in addition to the linked versions.
To do that simply add "?singleWSDL” to the URI (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789(v=vs.110).aspx)